# Is it possible to access an already deployed smart contract without using metamask?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, metamask

Suppose a user wants to access a contract on the blockchain hat was distributed by a company. Can it do this without the use of metamask? If so, how?

Comment: the easiest way would be to go to Etherscan page, the tab "Read contract" and interact with it there

Comment: @Nulik I want to design my dapp. I'm thinking about how to build an architecture in which a user accesses a smart contract already deployed on the blockchain.

Comment: the popular approach is to use web3 RPC API and use Infura nodes instead of your own.   a colledge student complexity job, you just need to get the ABI of the contract you are going to work with.

Comment: @Nulik how is it possible to obtain the ABI?

Comment: you should get it from the developer who created the contract

Comment: @Nulik ok, thanks a lot. I have a question to make sure I understand what you said.
A normal user wants to book a trip. How do I implement this in web3.js? I need to call public methods on the smart contract. but in a real case is it possible to get the ABI to do this in web3?

Comment: well, if the developer of the contract is a public company, they usually publish the sources of the contract on Etherscan and you can get the ABI from there. But if it is private, I don't think so

Comment: @Nulik So in a real case how does it work? Does it make more sense that it's private?

Comment: in real case it depends on the benefits the company will receive. Some companies like ConsenSys would publish source code because they are using it for marketing pursposes. But a company like Uber for example, in their use of the blockchain to collect logistics data from providers would never publish anything. Sometimes these companies also will opt for installing a private chain , I have seen many cases  when a group of companies belonging to some industry run their own chain with clique consensus.